# Wordpress - Multiple Meta Keys - Order by rank

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I have something like this

```
if(isset($_POST["select_1"]) or isset($_POST["select_2"])){
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => $meta_key_list1,
            'value' => $meta_key_val,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $meta_key_list2,
            'value' => $meta_key_val,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $meta_key_list3,
            'value' => $meta_key_val,
            'compare' => '='
        ),

    ),


);  
}else{
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'my_post_type',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'page_rank'
);    
}
```

I need show all pages which have set custom field "page_rank" and order it DESC. "Else" working good but first part not working. I try something like in "else" but this not working for multiple key.

Please do you know anyone how to solve this problem?
Thank you !

**EDIT:** 
Solved I changed OR to AND thank you for help

Comment: What are the values of `$meta_key_list`, and `$meta_key_val`, etc?

Comment: Also, how can you tell that it is "not working?"  What results are you getting back with that?

Comment: Thank you all, I solved it I only change OR to AND and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try `'compare' => 'LIKE'` instead of `'compare' => '='` and verify your keys and values in the meta query